# Parsing javascript dumped array using Qt into list of points

Tags: c++, regex, qt, parsing

I need to convert a dumped array of points to a list of points in qt using c++ so that I can further debug my application. I use chrome to copy the array object to a file and it will end up like this:

```
[
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 266.48351648351644
  },
  {
    "x": 2.3095238095238093,
    "y": 274.3003663003663
  },
  {
    "x": 3.3754578754578755,
    "y": 277.6758241758242
  }
]
```

My strategy is to open the file and find lines that have the character x or y in them and save each consecutive x,y in a point object:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnOpenFile_clicked()
{

    auto path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Browse for a array object file...");
    QFile file(path); // works fine

    if(file.exists(path) && file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QVector<QPointF> points;
        QString currentLine;
        qreal x;
        qreal y;

        // Regex rules for x and y
        QRegExp rX(":.*,");
        rX.setMinimal(true);
        QRegExp rY(":.*");
        rY.setMinimal(true);

        while(!stream.atEnd()) {

            bool xFound = false, yFound = false;
            currentLine = stream.readLine();

            // Get X value
            if(currentLine.contains("x", Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
                auto pos = rX.indexIn(currentLine);
                if(pos == 0) {
                    x = rX.capturedTexts()[0].toDouble();
                    xFound = true;
                }
            } else if(currentLine.contains("y", Qt::CaseInsensitive)) { // Get Y value
                auto pos = rY.indexIn(currentLine);
                if(pos == 0) {
                    y = rY.capturedTexts()[0].toDouble();
                    yFound = true;
                }
            }

            if(xFound)
            points.push_back({x,y});

        }
    }

}
```

I just noticed that my approach will not work because I only evaluate one line in each iteration of the while loop...and that will never work.

Second is my regex that even matches the `[` character!

Is there any smarter way of doing this parsing? the dumped file looks like a JSON to me but maybe not? if it is compatible with JSON is there an automated way of converting it?

Comment: The data looks like a JSON array, no? You might try to use `QJson*` classes instead. Did you?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel. Don't try to use regex for this. Read the file into a JSON document. Something like this should work (untested):

```
    QFile file("myfile.json");
    QVector<QPointF> points;

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());
        file.close();

        QJsonArray array = doc.array();

        for (auto &&point : array)
        {
            QJsonObject p = point.toObject();
            points.push_back({p["x"], p["y"]});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now it is interesting to compare the performance of my answer to yours :))

Comment: @SaeidYazdani, your answer probably will be faster since it's designed to only expect a very specific input, rather than any generic JSON string. The OP wasn't asking for the fastest method. They asked for a "smarter way". Using a QJsonDocument will be more robust if the input ever changes, and it's much less likely to have parsing errors over doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, of course, to read and parse it as a JSON file... But if you want to go old-school and do it using the loop, no one said you are limited to read one line per iteration... you can achieve what you want like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_btnOpenFile_clicked()
{

    auto path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Browse for a array object file...");
    QFile file(path); // works fine

    if(file.exists(path) && file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {

        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QString xLine;
        QString yLine;
        QVector<QPointF> mPoints;

        while(!stream.atEnd()) {

            xLine = stream.readLine();

            if(xLine.contains("x", Qt::CaseInsensitive)) { // Line has x in it
                yLine = stream.readLine(); // READ NEXT LINE!!!!
            } else { // Line is either Y or not a X line so we skip to next iteration
                continue;
            }

            // Debug the lines
            qDebug() << "X =" << xLine;
            qDebug() << "Y =" << yLine;

            // Parse and add the points to the array    
            auto xConvResult = false;
            auto yConvResult = false;

            // To discard trailing ',' of the X line
            auto xValue = xLine.split(":")[1].split(",")[0].toDouble(&xConvResult);
            auto yValue = yLine.split(":")[1].toDouble(&yConvResult);

            if(xConvResult  && yConvResult) {
               mPoints.push_back({xValue, yValue});
            }
        }

        file.close();
    }
}
```